# Two div on the top, one div on the bottom

Tags: html, css

That would look like:

```
#div1 #div2
  #div3
```

I tried to set `#div1` and `#div2` to `float left`, but some part of `#div3` come to top. What' the problem here?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="one"></div><div id="two"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="three"></div>


<style>
#one {
float:left
}

#two {
float:left
}

.clear {
clear:both;

}


</style>
```

Comment: div.clear is not necessary (in this case), you can set clear:both to div#three

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>aaa</title>
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#container {
    width: 211px;
}
.fl {
    float: left;
}

#bottom {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="fl">FLOAT LEFT 1</div>
        <div class="fl">FLOAT LEFT 2</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div id="bottom">Bottom Div</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

BTW, you can't make your floating div 100%; in width. In that case the first DIV will push the second floating div to the bottom, resulting in 3 divs ontop of eachother.

Answer (score 1):

`#div3` should have `clear:both`.

Answer (score 0):

See this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnZRs/1/

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Make `width:100%;` for div1, and div2, have I understood the question. Also, if that is the case.